# InfoPath 2010 not Returning Data from Access dB

Tags: ms-access, network-programming, connection, infopath, multi-user

I have been working on a submission form for two of our employees' to enter tax data. It is an InfoPath 2010 form, which is connecting to an Access 2010 accdb. The purpose of the form is to pull related data from two source tables (one from the old dB that was used, and the other from APX which houses additional information) to prefill as many fields as possible. Everything works fine when running it from my computer, or directly off our server. The problem I am running into now, is that our two users have access to the files, can open them with InfoPath Filler, but upon opening, they get the "InfoPath cannot connect to the data source...". The funny thing is, is that last week, they were able to connect and submit data with no problem (then one day I came back from lunch and it no longer worked). How I had to originally set them up was to create a certificate, make the forms full trust, added both user ID's as being able to have read write access. When I run the form from my desktop it works without a hitch. I even tried remapping to a mdb to see if it was a version issue. The dB is stored on a shared domain, \testdomain\, for arguments sake. Then they access the form via the same directory. Just to note, SharePoint is not connected in any way. All the searches I have done have yielded no solutions. I am thinking it is a networking issue, and have a meeting with the network admin in a few hours. But, what I can't figure out, is how it worked before, and not now. Does anyone have any suggestions or thoughts on what could be causing this? Just to clarify, I can run the same xsn form they run, from the same server location, without having the issue they do. I truly appreciate anything anyone might be able to offer!

[image: Screen Shot of the Error]

Comment: I am aware that most of the technical details have been omitted, so please let me know if/what you may need to be of assistance. Thank you again!

Comment: I also tried renaming the xsn file to a cabinet file and changing the connection paths from "C:\User\Example.accdb" to the unc, "\\SERVER\User\Example.accdb". Again it still works when I run it, but not when the other users do.

Comment: Make sure you don't have a cached version of the infopath form. open up Infopath filler, right click on the form and remove the form. then try opening the form again.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Nathan, I'll check it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally figured out what was causing the problem (totally feel dumb). Apparently the servers used randomly get backed up, and when they do, the permissions get overwritten. If anyone else runs into this, review the access permissions for the directory and all the files. Thanks Nathan for your advice!